# Python file processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment was to write a program which extracts the first/last names, birth year, and ID from a file, manipulate that information to create a username and  formatted ID, prompt the user for 3 test grades, calculate the average, and finally write all the information to a new file. This is the program I wrote, and the error I got is listed below the program.
Define main function

```
def main():
infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "r")
data = infile.read()
fName, lName, ID, year = data.split(",")
year = int(year)
```

Prompt the user for three test scores

```
grades = eval(input("Enter the three test scores separated by a comma: "))
```

Create a username

```
uName = (lName[:4] + fName[:2] + str(year)).lower()
converted_id = ID[:3] + "-" + ID[3:5] + "-" + ID[5:]
grade_1, grade_2, grade_3 = grades
```

Convert the grades to strings so they can be written to a new file

```
[grade_1, grade_2, grade_3] = [str(grade_1), str(grade_2), str(grade_3)]
```

Calculate the average

```
average =(grade_1 + grade_2+ grade_3)/3
```

Convert the average to a string

```
average = str(average)
```

Write the information the file

```
outfile = open("studentreport.txt", "w")
outfile.write("*******Student Report*******\nStudent Name:" + fName + " " + lName)
outfile.write("\nStudent ID:  " + converted_id + "\n" + "Username:    " + uName + "\n\n")
outfile.write("Grade 1:    " + grade_1 + "\n" "Grade 2:    " + grade_2 + "\n" + "Grade 3:    " + grade_3 + "\n" + "Average:    " + average)   

infile.close()
outfile.close()

main()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/ovi/Desktop/Python Project 1.py", line 34, in
>
> main()
>
> File "C:/Users/ovi/Desktop/Python Project 1.py", line 22, in main
>
> average =(grade_1 + grade_2+ grade_3)/3
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: So, you convert your `grades_x` to strings, and then try to add them together and divide by 3? Maybe store the string-converted grades in different named variables. Using `+` with strings concatenates them together, instead of adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your converted string grades to floats (or int)

```
average =(float(grade_1) + float(grade_2)+ float(grade_3))/3.0
average = str(average)
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I think I can also just move the lines around and make the grades as strings AFTER I calculated the average

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the variables of type `int` to strings.

```
outfile.write("Grade 1:    " + str(grade_1) + "\n" "Grade 2:    " + str(grade_2) + "\n" + "Grade 3:    " + str(grade_3) + "\n" + "Average:    " + str(average))
```

**OR**

You could simply do like this..

```
>>> gr1 = 23
>>> gr2 = 45
>>> gr3 = 56
>>> total = gr1+gr2+gr3
>>> avg = total/3
>>> l = [gr1, gr2, gr3, total, avg]
>>> print("GRade 1: {} grade 2: {} grade 3: {} total: {} average : {}".format(*l))
GRade 1: 23 grade 2: 45 grade 3: 56
```

Comment: I tought I did that here though:   [grade_1, grade_2, grade_3] = [str(grade_1), str(grade_2), str(grade_3)]

Comment: And I did a similar thing for the average. Is this wrong?

Comment: just convert the grades to strings while printing only. Your method of conversion is wrong. It would be, `l = [str(grade_1), str(grade_2), str(grade_3)] ; outfile.write("Grade 1: {} .....".format(*l))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you think you could elaborate why my method of conversion is wrong though? I am trying to understand this better, not just memorize it

Comment: you cant able to find the average for strings.. Do all the calculations with the data type as int.